# Problem compiling a C file

Tags: 14.04, games, zlib

I was trying to install Xmame 0.103 on Ubuntu 14.04. I had some problems installing it. It says that

```
*.c zlib.h: no such file or directory
```

I opened that file and I saw that zlib.h file was written in header section. I tried some packages regarding it but all in vain.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: No, I download it from here: [http://www.romnation.net/srv/emulators/75/mame/xMAME-v0-103-for-Linux.html](http://www.romnation.net/srv/emulators/75/mame/xMAME-v0-103-for-Linux.html)

Comment: Since you are installing from a .tar.bz2 file, it may help to review the answers to [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file).

Comment: I did configure it and then run make command. It is where the problem occurs.

Comment: sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev

Comment: I got another problem. Check this image: https://scontent-a-kul.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t1.0-9/10401872_786354618051014_2067290203187043122_n.jpg <img src="https://scontent-a-kul.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/t1.0-9/10401872_786354618051014_2067290203187043122_n.jpg">

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1; Install MAME:**
Open a Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following line in it:

```
sudo apt-get install mame mame-tools gnome-video-arcade sdlmame sdlmame-tools
```

**Step 2; MAME Configuration:**
Start now MAME with this command so that a hidden folder (**.mame**) is created in your home directory which will contain all emulator settings:

```
mame
```

You can now close the emulator. Run this command to create the configuration file for MAME:

```
cd ~/.mame && mame -cc
```

The "**mame.ini**" file will be created in the **~/.mame** folder. Edit now this file with this command:

```
sudo gedit ~/.mame/mame.ini
```

In "**rompath**", you can set your own ROM directory path or leave default paths:
[image]

Next, create the following directories in the **~/.mame** folder:

- nvram
- sta
- roms
- memcard
- inp
- comments
- snap
- diff
  You can create them all with this command:

  mkdir  ~/.mame/nvram memcard roms inp comments sta snap diff

You can access the rom folder with this command to place your downloaded roms in:

```
nautilus ~/.mame/roms
```

As for player controls, you can easily configure them from the main interface of MAME (**Configure General Inputs**):
[image]

**Note:** While playing a game with MAME, you can exit fullscreen mode by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for that but I want to install 0.103 and not 0.145 or 0.152 which is latest. It is because they don't run old games I have in my computer. I use to run these games on Windows computer but now I want to do the same but latest MAME is not running these old games. It shows some error regarding some images files.

Comment: Can you give me a error pleas?

Comment: Sure but can't do it right now. I'm using my ant's computer which has Windows 8 installed on it. I will post error as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: Mame error "The selected game is missing one or more required ROM or CHD images"

Comment: http://www.vg-resource.com/thread-21078.html